# Show view with related data in Datagrid shows No result Found

Tags: react-admin

With reference to this post: [Injecting List, Show, Edit, Create in any places](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59410436/injecting-list-show-edit-create-in-any-places/64364159#64364159)

I have written this code:

```
<Show {...props}>
  <SimpleShowLayout>
  ...
  <Fragment>
    <List
      {...props}
      resource="card_program_options"
      filterDefaultValues={{ card_id: 1 }}
      sort={{ field: "id", order: "ASC" }}
    >
      <Datagrid>
        <TextField source="card_id" />
        <TextField source="card_programs_id" />
      </Datagrid>
    </List>
  </Fragment>
  </SimpleShowLayout>
</Show>
```

But the only thing I see on the page is "No results found". Screenshoot below:

[image: screen shot show view no results found]

I see the request made in the backend and completes with a 200 response code but the table does not refresh like that on a simple list view. Am I missing something here.

Help is appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

The way that I got the list to show up is to register a <Resource ...> in the the App.js file for the grid that I wanted to generate!